# NIC interface names in /proc/interrupts

Tags: networking, ethernet, interrupts, linux

When I look at /proc/interrupts:

```
$ cat /proc/interrupts
           CPU0       CPU1
(...)
 12:          4          0    IO-APIC-edge  i8042
 14:        145   65310875    IO-APIC-edge  ide0
 50:          0          0   IO-APIC-level  uhci_hcd:usb5, Intel ICH7
 58:       5388    7983508   IO-APIC-level  libata
169:  812427252 1236572641   IO-APIC-level  skge, eth1
217:          6          0   IO-APIC-level  ehci_hcd:usb1, uhci_hcd:usb2
225:          0          0   IO-APIC-level  uhci_hcd:usb3
233:         60 3108720778   IO-APIC-level  uhci_hcd:usb4, skge
```

I can see two **skge** and one **eth1** entries. All of them are the network cards. Because of the general name "skge" (which is the name of the network driver of the card) I can't easily reocognize, which NIC occupies which interrupt.

**How to make linux use more descriptive names in the entries?**

Or: **Is there any alternative way to obtain INT information instead of /proc/interrupt?**

My final goal is to manipulate smp_affinities of the NICs.

Answer (score 2):

On RH based systems you can name each nic by means of **ifcfg-* scripts**.

Simply specify the MAC address of the nic in orther to associate it to the right HW device, then give it a device name of your choice.

This way you should have **"yournicname" listed instead of "eth1"**, so you can simply achieve your goal.

Here is **[a nice article](http://www.science.uva.nl/research/air/wiki/LogicalInterfaceNames)** with a number of ways you can follow to do this adjustment on various scenarios; depending on you distribution it may be more or less complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Look in /sys/class/net/***(interface)***/device/irq.

Set the affinity in /proc/irq/***(interrupt)***/smp_affinity.

I don't know why the skge driver isn't giving you individual devices; perhaps it can only use a single IRQ line for all interfaces?